# MySQL selecting Top 10 Records Based on an int field of a table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table called Book that has a field(BorrowTime) that will increment once it's being borrowed. something like below

i want to retrieve the top 10 records with the highest borrowtime.
my sql statement:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * from books order by BorrowTime DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
   echo $row['Title'];
}
```

it's not working and have infinite loop. does anyone know what goes wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that goes through an infinite loop

Comment: Code is correct. Problem somewhere else.

Comment: seems, fine.. try changing the variable names to avoid conflicts with other loops

Comment: i have try it in a new page. and it just never stopping printing the first record.. which mean it never exit from first record.

Comment: whats your php/mysql version and OS ?

Comment: i'm using XAMPP under windows.. never met this problem be4... not sure why it never exit upon fetching first record = =

Comment: i have settle out the problem... thx all

Comment: Please post the solution to your problem as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

no problem with your code, but try debuging using this script,

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * from books order by BorrowTime DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    print_r($row);
    exit;//force exit script to debuging, are we get correct result or not
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT Title from books order by BorrowTime DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
   echo $row['Title'];
}
```

Because you are only using the field 'Title', and no other fields from that table.

Also, when this field is defined as 'title' than $row['Title'] wont show anything, because you should than use $row['title']